# Java Spring IOC overriding property of bean

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

I need 3 beans, each with 3 properties 2 of them are related properties `values from anothers beans` but they differ in only 1 property. I have something like this:

```xml
<bean id="a" class="myClassPath" scope="prototype">
    <property name='status' value='#{otherBean.myMethod()}'/>
    <property name='code'   value='#{otherBean.myOtherMethod()}'/>
    <property name='typeOf' value='1'/>
</bean>

<bean id="b" class="myClassPath" scope="prototype">
    <property name='status' value='#{otherBean.myMethod()}'/>
    <property name='code'   value='#{otherBean.myOtherMethod()}'/>
    <property name='typeOf' value='2'/>
</bean>

<bean id="c" class="myClassPath" scope="prototype">
    <property name='status' value='#{otherBean.myMethod()}'/>
    <property name='code'   value='#{otherBean.myOtherMethod()}'/>
    <property name='typeOf' value='3'/>
</bean>
```

This code is very redundant. Can I if like define a `bean` and some kind override only the property `typeOf`?
**UPDATE**

the value of status and code are defined in others beans using `Spring language this is in some way a example.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take advantage of the bean template inheritance for a scenario like this:

```
    <bean id="yourCommonProperties"  abstract="true" scope="prototype">
        <property name="status" value='#{otherBean.myMethod()}'/>
        <property name="code" value='#{otherBean.myOtherMethod()}'/>
    </bean>
```

Here we are not specifying the class but just sharing the common properties and refer this using *parent* attribute in each of the bean definition as:

```
    <bean id="a" class="myClassPath" parent="yourCommonProperties" scope="prototype">
        <property name='typeOf' value='1'/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="b" class="myClassPath" parent="yourCommonProperties" scope="prototype">
        <property name='typeOf' value='2'/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="c" class="myClassPath" parent="yourCommonProperties" scope="prototype">
        <property name='typeOf' value='3'/>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yup, just in your class definition do as follows:

```
...
private boolean status = true;
private int code = 13;
private int typeOf;
...
```

and then Spring config would be like:

```
<bean id="a" class="myClassPath" scope="prototype">
   <property name='typeOf' value='1'/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Use the constructor or method decorated with `@PostConstruct` annotation instead of initializing the fields on the declaration.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Give reason please, instead saying: use it that way because.

Answer (score 1):

For example use `autowired="byName"`, and create beans with `status` and `code` names:

```
<bean id="status" class="java.lang.Boolean">
    <constructor-arg value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="code" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <constructor-arg value="13"/>
</bean>

<bean id="a" class="myClassPath" autowired="byName" scope="prototype">
    <property name='typeOf' value='1'/>
</bean>

<bean id="b" class="myClassPath" autowired="byName" scope="prototype">
    <property name='typeOf' value='2'/>
</bean>

<bean id="c" class="myClassPath" autowired="byName" scope="prototype">
    <property name='typeOf' value='3'/>
</bean>
```

Comment: That could be tricky. I do not say it wouldn't work, but just imagine following. myClassPath have `private java.lang.Integer code;` using it that way three instances would share exact same piece of memory, so if one of them modify it others would have the value changed as well. As I said it could be tricky. Sometimes we want this feature, but more often we do not.

Comment: @abc No, it is not, because Integer class is **immutable**. You can't change value of an Integer instance. But if a variable points to an Integer instance, you can make it point to other instance, with other value. And it won't affect other classes. What you said is like saying that if two classes have `String textField = "someText";` then if you change the value of `textField` in one of the classes, then the second will also be affected. It is not true, because String class also is immutable, like Integer.